# ItemTemplate combox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I wanted to store two Item in the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ComboxBox.

1. String which will be displayed in the ComboBox
2. Index which won't be shown in the CombBox

I explored and found that ItemTemplate Property can do this.
Can somebody Please provide me the sample for this.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `ItemTemplate`, what you need would be like:

```
combobox.add(new ListItem("string", "index");
```

Comment: Will String be displayed in the Combo if i do this??

Comment: only one value will be dislayed in the combo, you can access the other value like
`((ListItem)(cmbWH.SelectedItem)).ShortName/LongName`

Comment: Sorry I forgot mention Its new comboBox.I am using WinRT ComboBox.Updated the Question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Application1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="768" 
    d:DesignWidth="1366">
    <Grid 
        x:Name="LayoutRoot" 
        Background="#FF0C0C0C">
        <Rectangle
            x:Name="rect"
            Fill="Black"
            Margin="40,40,0,0" />

        <ComboBox
            Margin="40,40,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="{Binding Text}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Application1
{
    partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class MyItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public List<MyItem> Items { get; set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.Items = new List<MyItem>();
            this.Items.Add(new MyItem { Text = "Item 1", Id = 1 });
            this.Items.Add(new MyItem { Text = "Item 2", Id = 2 });
        }
    }
}
```